# Is there any python method that is able to extract value of key between [ ] sign in a long string?

Tags: python, geodjango, epsg

I am using geodjango ,and i would  extract the value of "EPSG" from the long string returned from a code as below:

PROJCS["WGS_1984_UTM_Zone_42N",GEOGCS["WGS 84",DATUM["WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326
"]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],PARAMETER["central_meri
dian",69],PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9996],PARAMETER["false_easting",500000],PARAMETER["false_northing",0],UNIT["Meter",1],AXIS["Easting",EAST],AXIS["Northing",NORTH]] crs_name

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions

```
import re

text = '''PROJCS["WGS_1984_UTM_Zone_42N",GEOGCS["WGS 84",DATUM["WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326 "]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],PARAMETER["central_meri dian",69],PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9996],PARAMETER["false_easting",500000],PARAMETER["false_northing",0],UNIT["Meter",1],AXIS["Easting",EAST],AXIS["Northing",NORTH]] crs_name'''
lst = re.findall(r'\["EPSG","(\d+)', text)
print(lst)
```

Prints:

```
['7030', '6326']
```